# Stop embedded swf file

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a video that is in SWF format and I need to have it embedded in another SWF file. This I have no problem with. The video get's embedded, plays when it need, but I can't figure out how to stop it. My code is like this:

```
var k:Object = new videoClass();
video = k as MovieClip;
parentObject.addChild(video);
```

Now, when I want to unload the video I call this:

```
parentObject.removeChild(video);
video.stop();
video = null;
```

Sadly, the video does unload but I can still hear the sound playing. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried video.stop before using removeChild?

Comment: Can you post some more code? Do you have any listeners attached to your object?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Why not use video into a video format, like FLV ? SWF is not as optimized for video as FLV is.

The loaded SWF have only a static video into it's timeline, or have any programming on it?
Maybe you're dealing with a SWF with code which makes it play it's video.

If that's the case, you can access public methods from it and control it.

```
var video:MovieClip = new videoClass() as MovieClip;
parentObject.addChild(video);
...
video.publicMethodToStopAllMedia();
parentObject.removeChild(video);
```

Comment: The video is a flv file converted to swf using http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/ so I don't think it has any code in it.